# Can anyone explain the reasoning behind this post?

Tags: predictive-modeling, regression, statistics

I am reading [THIS blog post,](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-feature-attribution-method-to-supposedly-rule-them-all-shapley-values-f3e04534983d)
and I do not understand the logic behind this part:

[image: Pic from Post]

Why is the relu here `max(0, Xavg - X)` ? And even so, it does not really explain the values obtained in the two situations where `X1 = X2 = 0`, `X1 = 1` and `X2 = 0`, and `X1 = X2 = 1`.

Can someone please explain this in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

"Weight of $-4$" seems to be the key thing you're missing.  Translating a little, the neuron's value is $\operatorname{relu}(5-4x_1-4x_2)$.

Oh, and there seems to be a typo in the post:
"Then, if X2 also gets switched to 0" should be "switched to 1"